# How do I set the AppId for the Bing Azure Search API in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, bing-api

How do I authenticate my request in Javascript? With the old API, the structure of the request was:
    http://api.search.live.net/json.aspx?AppId=&Query=&sources=web

With the Bing Azure Search API, the required syntax is:
    https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?Query='Xbox'&$top=10&$skip=20&$format=ATOM

How do I specify the AppId in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

> use Base64 encoding like this, on the string ":"+yourAppIDKey

```
//initialize Base64 object
var Base64={_keyStr:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",encode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i,s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=Base64._utf8_encode(e);while(f<e.length){n=e.charCodeAt(f++);r=e.charCodeAt(f++);i=e.charCodeAt(f++);s=n>>2;o=(n&3)<<4|r>>4;u=(r&15)<<2|i>>6;a=i&63;if(isNaN(r)){u=a=64}else if(isNaN(i)){a=64}t=t+this._keyStr.charAt(s)+this._keyStr.charAt(o)+this._keyStr.charAt(u)+this._keyStr.charAt(a)}return t},decode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i;var s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g,"");while(f<e.length){s=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));o=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));u=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));a=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));n=s<<2|o>>4;r=(o&15)<<4|u>>2;i=(u&3)<<6|a;t=t+String.fromCharCode(n);if(u!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(r)}if(a!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(i)}}t=Base64._utf8_decode(t);return t},_utf8_encode:function(e){e=e.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");var t="";for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r)}else if(r>127&&r<2048){t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6|192);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}else{t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>12|224);t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6&63|128);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}}return t},_utf8_decode:function(e){var t="";var n=0;var r=c1=c2=0;while(n<e.length){r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r);n++}else if(r>191&&r<224){c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&31)<<6|c2&63);n+=2}else{c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);c3=e.charCodeAt(n+2);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&15)<<12|(c2&63)<<6|c3&63);n+=3}}return t}}

$.ajax
({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: "json",
  headers:{
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Base64.encode(":"+youAppIdKey)
  },
  success: function (data){
    console.log("yo");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log(data['d']['results'][0]['MediaUrl']);
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log("some error", XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

> if you face CORS error, use SimpleHTTPServer from your website folder for local testing, by typing this in the terminal

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```